# Get user profile picture url

Tags: web-part, picture, promoted-links

I'm using Promoted links Web part and i want to show a user picture on the background of the tile. How can  i get the user picture? I'm trying to do this with no code.

The only way to add a picture is to use its url, but if he changes his profil pic the image will no longer exist... Do i have to upload the picture by myself somewhere? Or maybe upload it on sharepoint? But then whenever he changes his picture i will have to change it in my promoted links list too...

how can i achieve his?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By inspecting the source code i noticed the profile pic is set like this: `background-image:url(/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=L&username=usernamehere);​`

So I used the same url in my promoted links list and when ever a user change his profile picture the url is returning the right pic too.

Because of the cache files the changed pic can't be seen imediatly. So I need to clear it i want to see the new picture. But it works and it's a no code solution.

Comment: Looks like a very good solution.

Comment: The querystring-paremeter is not called `username`, it's called `accountname`.

Comment: Cleared browser cache but still image is not updated, seems like sharepoint is having some other internal cache

Answer (score 0):

Without code, you won't fix the issue on the changing profile picture. With code, you could solve this with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104.aspx

You could also think about using a content by search webpart to show people and pictures and somehow filter the result to get the same people.

Comment: Can't we use a script editor? And load all the pictures? but then i don't know how to set the picture in the right tile

Comment: Yes, you could use the script editor.And you need to have a key like email address or username in the tile to set the picture.