# How to filter soap response for user profile image

Tags: sharepoint-server, soap

Hi I'm using SharePoint 2010 and attempting to filter soap response with code below:

```
 // the result is burried in XML markup so we look for the right node
 $(xData.responseXML).find('Values').each(function()  
 {  
 // get the text property of the node and display it
 var name = $(this).find('Value').text(); 
 // alert(name); 
 });
```

This alerts ever property in the output but I require the PictureURLPublic only.
How can I do this. By the way I've tried 'getElementsByTagName' but this causes an error. Is there another way?

Response:
falsefalseUserProfile_GUIDPublic9f0278aa-6969-48f4-8d67-e604b16bd639falsefalseAccountNamePublicwl_dom1\rajchfalsefalseFirstNamePublicRajfalsefalseSPS-PhoneticFirstNamePublicfalsefalseLastNamePublicChahalfalsefalseSPS-PhoneticLastNamePublicfalsefalsePreferredNamePublicRaj ChahfalsefalseSPS-PhoneticDisplayNamePublicfalsefalseWorkPhonePublic+441952526902falsefalseDepartmentPublicIT Service Delivery - MI TeamfalsefalseTitlePublicSharepoint Senior DeveloperfalsefalseSPS-JobTitlePublicSharepoint Senior DeveloperfalsefalseManagerPublicwl_dom1\chrisholfalsefalseAboutMePublicfalsefalsePersonalSpacePublic/personal/wl_dom1_rajch/falsefalsePictureURLPublichttp://my.lifecapnet.com:80/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/wl_dom1_rajch_MThumb.jpgfalsefalseUserNamePublicrajchfalsefalseQuickLinksPublicfalsefalseWebSitePublicfalsefalsePublicSiteRedirectPublicfalsefalseSPS-Dotted-

Comment: can you post the response XML?

Comment: BTW you can use regex to match the response for image. for example like this (/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test($(this).find('Value').text())

Comment: Do you have the loginname? Check this -> http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/163273/10271

Comment: Updated question with response XML

Comment: Hi Could anyone help wit obtaining the correct tag now that I've posted the soap response pls? I require PictureURLPublic